# Value returned by API not converted to Date

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, angular7

On an Angular 7 application I have the following model:

```
public getTopPosts() {
  return this.httpClient.get<TopPostsResponse>>('top-posts');
}
```

Where TopPostsResponse is:

```
export interface TopPostsResponse {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  created: Date;
}
```

I am calling the service in a component method:

```
getTopPosts(): Observable<PostModel[]> {

  return this.postService.getTopPosts().pipe(

    map((response: TopPostsResponse) => { 

      console.log(response.created);
      console.log(response.created instanceof Date);

      var created = new Date(response.created);
      console.log(created);
      console.log(created instanceof Date);

      return {
        id: response.id, 
        created: response.created,
        title: response.title
      };

    }));

}
```

The problem is when I check if response.created is a Date I get False:

```
console.log(response.created); >> 2019-01-24T13:03:10.123684
console.log(response.created instanceof Date); >> FALSE

var created = new Date(response.created); 
console.log(created); >> Thu Jan 24 2019 13:03:10 GMT+0000 (WET)
console.log(created instanceof Date); >> TRUE
```

It seems the service is not converting the value returned by the API to a Date type but still is a valid Date because I am able to create an instance of it.

What am I missing?

Comment: `response.created`  is a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Typescript does not automatically convert the raw data from the request to a certain type. You will have to parse it by yourself.

```
return {
    id: response.id, 
    created: new Date(response.created),
    title: response.title
  };
```

Typescript compiler runs before the build, not in run time. So it does not know what will come in the response from the API. The Typescript code is transpiled and then a javascript code is generated, so the type checking occurs only when you are writing the code. After that, when it `really runs`, it won't analyze what kind of data is coming from an outside source.

Comment: So you saying that do make this work correctly I should use Map even when mapping the response from the server, eg., in return this.httpClient.get<TopPostsResponse>>('top-posts'); If not then the TopPostsResponse types are not being converter.